# Unable to take screen shot of failed test case using firefox

Tags: firefox, selenium

I am unable to take screen shot of a failed test case using Selenium webdriver and Firefox.

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)

public class screenshot{
public String Email;
public String password;
private WebDriver driver;
private String baseUrl;
private boolean acceptNextAlert = true;
private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();




public screenshot(String username,String password){
    this.Email =username;
    this.password=password;
}


@Parameters
public static Collection<Object[]>getdata(){
    Object[] [] data=new Object[2][2];
    data[0][0] =" xyz@gmail.com";
    data[0][1] ="12344";
    data[1][0] ="86826332@gmail.com";
    data[1][1] ="ytwey";



    return Arrays.asList(data);

}



  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {

  driver = new FirefoxDriver();
  baseUrl = "https://accounts.google.com/";
  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }

  @Test

  public void testUntitled5() throws IOException {
  try{
   driver.get(baseUrl + "gmail login page");
   driver.findElement(By.id("Email")).clear();
   driver.findElement(By.id("Email")).sendKeys(Email);

   driver.findElement(By.id("Passwd")).sendKeys(password);
   driver.findElement(By.id("signIn")).click();
   Thread.sleep(1000);
  }catch(Exception e){
 File scrFile =        ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);  
FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("C:\\Documents and       Settings\\japarna\\Desktop\\deepikafailure.png")); 
  }

   }
```

Program is running successfully, but I am unable to get a screenshot of the failed test case.
Is there any alternate coding apart from this? It works in Firefox version 30 beta but Firefox version 29 it is not working. Is it a version problem or does any code need to be added?

Comment: What selenium version are you currently using?

Answer (score 0):

This is the method I use and it works on Firefox 29

```
public String captureScreen(WebDriver driver) {

        String path;
        try {
            // WebDriver augmentedDriver = new Augmenter().augment(driver);
            File source = ((TakesScreenshot) driver)
                    .getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
            String datestamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd_hh_mm_")
                    .format(new Date());
            path = "C:\\workspace\\screenshot\\errors\\" + datestamp
                    + source.getName();
            FileUtils.copyFile(source, new File(path));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            path = "Failed to capture screenshot: " + e.getMessage();
        }
        return path;

    }
```